# Is it possible to map multiple select statement into columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table:

```
code(integer) |number_of_data(integer)| date (Date)
```

I need to:

1. Group by day, this for tho month of june only
2. Select sum of number_of_data for the day for each code != 0
3. Select n_data for code = 0

For the first 2 points I came up with:

```
select sum(number_of_data) nData, TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') dayOfMonth from T1 
where to_char( date, 'mm') = 6 
 and code <> 0
 group by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') order by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD');
```

it gives me this table result:

```
nData | dayOfMonth
```

which is fine, anyway I'm missing requirement 3, whose query would be the same but with the opposite condition (code=0).
Is there a way to add it to the above query so to get this result:

```
nData | nDataZero | dayOfMonth
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there will only be one entry with `CODE = 0` for each day, then you can do:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE CODE WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE number_of_data END ) AS nData,
       MAX( CASE CODE WHEN 0 THEN number_of_data END ) AS nDataZero,
       EXTRACT( DAY FROM "Date" ) AS dayOfMonth
FROM   T1 
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM "Date" ) = 6 
GROUP BY EXTRACT( DAY FROM "Date" )
ORDER BY EXTRACT( DAY FROM "Date" );
```

If there will be more than one entry then you will need to specify how it is to be handled (i.e. change `MAX` to `SUM` if you want the total of the `CODE = 0` values).

Comment: I just substituted NULL with 0 so to get 0 if no occurs with event code 0 are present

Answer (score 1):

Whit some regards to the syntax in MS Sql. This is a way i would solve this in a  oracle sql-like way:)

```
SELECT sum(nData) nData , sum(nDataZero) nDataZero, T1 
from (
select sum(number_of_data) nData, 0 nDataZero , TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') dayOfMonth 
from T1 
where to_char( date, 'mm') = 6  and code <> 0  
group by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') 
order by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') 
UNION 
select 0 nData, sum(number_of_data) nDataZero , TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') dayOfMonth 
from T1 
where to_char( date, 'mm') = 6 and code == 0 
group by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') 
order by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD')) 
group by T1;
```

Rgds

Comment: This will throw a `NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION` error as you haven't told it how to group `nData` and `nDataZero` in the outer `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. You will have to sum(nData), sum(nDataZero) in the firsta select..Thanks for pointing my slopiness out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE to separate data into 2 slots, code=0 and code<>0:

```
select sum(number_of_data) nData, TO_CHAR(date, 'DD') dayOfMonth, CASE WHEN code = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 AS x  
from T1 
where to_char( date, 'mm') = 6 
group by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD'), x 
order by TO_CHAR(date, 'DD');
```